# Reshape dataframe year variables

Tags: pandas, dataframe

How I do reshape/transform:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year':[2014,2015,2014,2015],'KS4':[True, True, False, False], 'KS5':[False, False, True, False]})

     KS4    KS5  Year
0   True  False  2014
1   True  False  2015
2  False   True  2014
3  False  False  2015
```

To get:

```
    KS4   KS5
0  2014  2014
1  2015
```

Comment: There are simpler answers that are more performant. See mine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple simple answers involving reconstructing the DataFrame with Series.

```
df.iloc[:, :-1].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(df.Year.values[x]))
```

This does the same thing more explicitly with a loop.

```
pd.DataFrame({col: pd.Series(df['Year'].values[df[col]]) for col in df.columns[:-1]})

    KS4     KS5
0  2014  2014.0
1  2015     NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
df.KS4=df.KS4.mul(df.Year)
df.KS5=df.KS5.mul(df.Year)

df.set_index('Year').stack().to_frame().replace({0:np.nan}).dropna()\
           .unstack().fillna('').reset_index(drop=True)
Out[159]: 
        0      
      KS4   KS5
0    2014  2014
1    2015
```

EDIT drop column level by using `df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()`

Or

```
df=df.set_index('Year').stack().to_frame().replace({0:np.nan}).dropna()\
           .unstack().fillna('')
df.mul(df.index.values).reset_index(drop=True)

Out[183]: 
      0      
    KS4   KS5
0  2014  2015
1  2014
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are only looking where the values are True. If so...

```
dd = dd.groupby(['Year'], as_index=False).sum()

dd.KS4 = dd.KS4 * dd.Year
dd.KS5 = dd.KS5 * dd.Year

dd.replace(0, '', inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
f = lambda d: d.mul(d.index.to_series().astype(str), 0)
df.groupby('Year').any().pipe(f).reset_index(drop=True)

    KS4   KS5
0  2014  2014
1  2015
```